# Recover keyPassword Eas Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

Export my jks with which I generated the PEM and reset the signing certificate in play console. But now when I want to add my jks file to eas it asks me to fill in KeystorePath, keystorePassword, keyAlias and **keyPassword**.
But I can't find a way to get the **keyPassword**, the other data I already have.
I need help!